# What should we do for Arduino Day 2014?

Tags: discussion, events

From the [official Arduino site](http://day.arduino.cc/):

> Arduino Day is a worldwide celebration of Arduino’s first 10 years. It's 24 hours full of events – both official and independent, anywhere around the world – where people interested in Arduino can meet, share their experiences, and learn more.
>
> Who can participate?
> Arduino invites all Arduino user groups, makerspaces, hackerspaces, fablabs, associations, teachers, pros, and newbies to participate. Let’s make this the biggest birthday party yet!

Arduino Day is on the 29<sup>th</sup> of March. What can we do to join in on the worldwide event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Showcase '14 is coming to Arduino Stack Exchange! (Updated 3/19/14)](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/153/project-showcase-14-is-coming-to-arduino-stack-exchange-updated-3-19-14)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Project Showoff Day/Week!

Arduino hackers are almost always working on creating something interesting. Lets have an event inviting users to post pictures and descriptions of their coolest  projects, and we could <s>drool over</s> discuss them.

To participate, the user must post:

- Atleast one picture (*necessary*)
- Video link on Youtube (*optional*)
- Aim of the project
- Basic breakdown of components
- Short description or video^ of working

The projects can be anything but **must** utilise an Arduino board.

---

This could be done on either main, meta or chat. After a [discussion with Peter](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8489/conversation/arduino-day-discussion), we are leaning towards holding this on a single question on main.

The timeline could also be longer, encompassing a week starting from 23<sup>th</sup> and culminating on 29<sup>th</sup>.

Comment: Having discussed this on chat, I think it sounds like a good idea. It would hopefully be a good way to encourage new folks to sign up and post their projects.

Comment: I don't really know about the *must utilise an Arduino board.* It might be better to say it must use any microcontroller that an official board contains. Size may be an issue with an official board.

Comment: ok say I participate and created something original, how would I know that  someone here won't steal my idea? can we have some copyright?

Comment: @Fischer http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225488/200868

Answer (score 1):

### Kickoff of the *[Blog / Project of the month?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/blog-project-of-the-month)*

This is similar to [AsheeshR's answer](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/220). With this we might be able to:

- Generate new visitors
- Gain network-wide attention (possibly)
- Generate much quality content (in one post, I know)
- Rally excitement for our site from the current users.

It seems like a great way to celebrate Arduino's 10th anniversary.

Answer (score -1):

Partner with Instructibles.com. The people there are CRAZY for the Arduino!

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't think is a bad idea, and if it is someone should say why