# Blog / Project of the month?

Tags: discussion

It might be a bit early for things like this, but (since there are so many interesting and surprising things being done with Arduino) how about some kind of rolling community interaction and showcasing a bit like [photography.SE's photo of the week](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest), where people post interesting Arduino projects they've made or heard about, and the most upvoted every month / fortnight / week gets showcased in, say, a short blog post where the project's author or a volunteer explains why it's interesting?

Something like this done right could build traffic and activity that turns into better questions and answers, and more loyal enthusiastic users.

---

There might be loads of blogs and showcase sites out there that do this sort of showcasing really well already which we might not want to compete with - in which case, this question might be a good place to drop some links.

If there are a few but they're inconsistent or infrequently updated, doing something like a "project of the month" based on a continuously open place to post submissions could be a nice way to focus attention on this site as a hub, while also promoting other sites with (hopefully popular) links through.

Answer (score 1):

While I wholly support the idea, it may be *too early* to direct attention on a blog before we even establish a *core* community of users for the site itself. The site is about Q&A first and foremost, and that needs a fair bit of focus for now. 
Even the Photography contest you link to was started almost 2 years after the site went into its public beta.

A once a week or month event in chat would be a good starting point to move towards a full-fledged vote and blog event. In fact, I posted [this idea](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/65) on another discussion.

Comment: I like the idea of a one-off event with plenty of build-up time, which could evolve into something regular if it goes well. I might suggest Meta rather than chat to start with as it's easier to link to, easier to browse/compare entries, and better shows off the SE format for any experienced Arduino people who aren't used to SE (i.e. ideal new users).

Answer (score 1):

### What's the point of linking users *out* of the site? Why can't we hold a contest?

I love the idea. However, I don't really know how valuable it would be to link users out of the site unless we just wanted recurring visitors. Not to mention, it'll be *link-only answers galore.* A better solution would be to have a user to *interact* with the site, giving the user interest in the site and the content.

One thing that we would have to think about is the logistical standpoint. To do such a project, it might be a little non-SE style to make many posts that are too localised. We'll have to draw a definite line on how far is too far. For example:

- *How do I make a robot that is 5x2x3, follows only green light, and plays a song when it can't find any green light?* ***Way* too pushy.**
- *How do I mobilize by robot?* **Much better.**

A "series" might be better. (See [Q&A Series Ideas](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/qa-series-ideas?rq=1).) That way, it won't be too localised, it won't be able to be a link-only answer, and it would generate **valuable traffic**, not just someone who visits the site once a month. However, **it is up to the poster to decide on it it's too localised or not.**

---

One note: we should open another thread on the logistics if we want to start this.

**Maybe we could start this on [Arduino Day 2014](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/what-should-we-do-for-arduino-day-2014)?**